# How can I address the issue of a broken desktop screen with my manager?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, communication, software, task-management

Due to lockdown, I was given desktop to work from home. One day I thought of cleaning desktop table and monitor as well. I kept my monitor on a box and started cleaning the table. I was keeping all the things on floor which are on table. Accidentally, I moved back and the box on which I kept desktop moved slightly and monitor has fallen on the object placed in front of it.

Immediately I didn't see any cracks on my screen. It was all good. But when I tried to login into it I see some rainbow lines and few cracks on screen. I am scared to address this issue to my manager and also I'm afraid that, am I responsible to pay for the replacement. I asked one of my friend , who works in hardware department ( not my company IT person, some outsider) he told me it costs around ₹7k to ₹8k ($100USD) for screen replacement and I cannot afford that much as i'm the only person earning in my family.Please suggest how i should address this issue to my manager.

Comment: Can you still work despite the cracks and rainbow lines?

Comment: Yes I'm able to work .. But I am scared to address this issue

Comment: If there was an accident in the workplace, who would have to pay for it then? Also, we can't answer if your company will try to make you pay for it, obviously. We can help you with how to address this with your manager.

Comment: Hi, can state wich Country this is?

Comment: Country is india

Comment: @Erik yes pls suggest

Comment: hi. I edited your question for clarity, please feel free to edit/roll back

Comment: It costs $100 for a private individual. It is a rounding error for a company. They have spare equipment everywhere and probably has no problem sourcing replacement parts for cheap.

Comment: @Rtu people good effort into answering your question, please do not vandalise it.

Comment: Please don't delete your question after it was answered

Comment: If you really want your question deleted, please flag it for moderator attention rather than removing the content.

Comment: Hi @Zhu, as you saw you are unable to delete this post since it received answers with a positive score. If you'd like to have this question disassociated from your account, please contact the community team for that using [this procedure.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tell your IT support.

Let them know that you were cleaning and accidentally knocked a heavy object onto the screen. The computer is functional, you are able to work, but the screen is definitely damaged.

Ask what you can do to help with getting it fixed. Accept responsibility and let them know.

I've been in tech support for multiple years, and the stupidest things show up.  An accident is not stupid. It is very boring actually. Employees with kids will show up with just some of the craziest stupidest things, like peanut butter sandwich inside CD drive, or using paint on the screen. What annoys IT support is the deflection of responsibility, pretending nothing is wrong, being demanding, and blaming others.

Accept responsibility, apologize, and ask what you can do to help.

Even if it costs $100 to replace, you're not the first to damage office equipment, you won't be the last, and it really is very common (Laptop on car roofs fly off? Run over by a car? Dropped out a window?)

You hope they won't take it out of the paycheck, but they can, or they might just not. It wasn't deliberate (to get an upgrade), you didn't sell company property, or do something criminal. By and large this is a very, **very** mundane event.

Comment: Yes it's a desktop not laptop @Solar Mike

Comment: @Rtu yes, I was sure I had read it clearly, this was for Nelson to update the answer which has been done... So I have voted for it - do you think it is worth a vote?

Comment: “Accept responsibility” does not mean you accept you have to pay for it. It is a workplace accident, which should be responsibility of the company. They were the ones that didn’t supply you with a proper monitor stand and forced you to work in a less suitable environment.

Comment: Nelson: In most countries they can absolutely not take money out of your pay check.

Comment: In India you can't even quit without your bosses approval, so I don't know if common standards apply.

Comment: @Ztu I knew that from reading the original question... Was just getting the answer updated, thought you would get that.